# How to find the norm of this operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, linear-transformations, lp-spaces

Find the norm of the operator that is given by

$T\colon L^1[0,1]\to L^1[0,1]$
such that 
$T(f)=g f$ 
where $g$ is essentially bounded.

I proved that it's bounded linear operator and 
$ \lVert T\rVert \leqslant\lVert g\rVert_{\infty}$

but i didn't find a function that make the inequality be equality.

**I think that we could use something related to the duality of $L^p$ spaces ($L^1$ and $L^{\infty}$) to prove the inverse inequality but i don't know if that is possible or it would make the answer harder.

Comment: The constant map $f=1$ is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Crostul it gives me the 1norm of g not the infinity norm

Comment: I don't think such a function exists in general. You need a sequence of functions with support in smaller and smaller regions. The support should where g is large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed $\varepsilon \in (0,\lVert g\rVert_\infty)$, there exists a set of positive measure $A$ such that $g(x)\geqslant\lVert g\rVert_\infty-\varepsilon$ for almost every $x\in A$. Define $f(x):=\operatorname{sign}(g(x))\mathbf 1_A(x)$. Then $\lVert f\rVert_1=\lambda(A)$ and 
$$\lVert T(f)\rVert_1=\int_{[0,1]}\left|g\right|\mathbf 1_A\geqslant \left(\lVert g\rVert_\infty-\varepsilon\right)\lambda(A)=\left(\lVert g\rVert_\infty-\varepsilon\right)\lVert f\rVert_1$$
hence $\lVert T\rVert\geqslant \lVert g\rVert_\infty-\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we get the wanted inequality.

Comment: Very obvious and clear explanation,a clever answer ,,thanks alot "شكراً لك كثيراً"